# css3 column-count property

Tags: firefox, css, opera, explorer

i've the following short css code

```
 div#mydiv{
  border-style: none; 
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  column-width: 15em;
  column-gap: 2em;
  column-count:2;
  -moz-column-width: 15em;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
  -moz-column-count:2;
  -webkit-column-count:2;
  -webkit-column-width: 15em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;   
  box-shadow: #ccc 0 0 15px;
  }
```

Now, on Firefox this work great and show 2 columns of text. On Opera this works but it is super weird, instead of showing 2 columns of text, it shows 3 columns!

so firefox:

bla    bla
 
bla    bla
 
bla    bla
bla    bla
bla    bla

Opera

bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla

Explorer

blablablablablablabla

I would like to know what is wrong with opera and if there is a way to have explorer show text in columns.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason for css3? If not, you can do this simply with css like:

```
#container {
    width:800px;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width:400px;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width:400px;
}
```

And

Html:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left">..</div>
<div id="right">..</div>
</div>
```

Code might not be exacly right, just to give you example.

Comment: by doing so, i've to divide the text equally by hand between the 2 div left and right. The column property is stylish and no metter how much text you write it divides the text automatically

Comment: Well there we have a reason, and good one :) ..cant help you much more, but css3 is still supported poorly with some browsers. You might find this site usefull to check how your page looks with different browser: http://browsershots.org/